# Cannot find function similar to liftM2

Tags: haskell, monads

```
myLiftM2 ::  Monad m => (a -> a1 -> m b) -> m a -> m a1 -> m b
myLiftM2 f x y = x >>= (\r1 -> y >>= (\r2 -> f r1 r2))
```

In liftM2 f return b, but myLiftM2 return m b

Comment: It's does not show up often in practice and it's easy to write in terms of `liftM2` and `join`: `myLiftM2 = ((join.).) . liftM2`.

Comment: is7s, I beg to disagree.  I've run into this function several times in practice, but I usually resort to do notation instead of using a function.

Comment: This is called `bindM2` in `Control.Monad.Parallel`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Use `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a` since a plain lift will return `m (m a)`. E.g. write

```
join $ liftM2 f a b
```

**But also...**

`liftM`s can also be written with `Applicative` -- e.g.

```
liftM2 a b c   == a <$> b <*> c
liftM3 a b c d == a <$> b <*> c <*> d
```

etc.

In this case, if you're willing to write in that style, you can write it cleanly and easily:

```
import Control.Applicative

myLiftM2 :: (Monad m, Applicative m) => (a -> a1 -> m b) -> m a -> m a1 -> m b
myLiftM2 f x y = join $ f <$> x <*> y
```

**Edit:**
As Daniel Wagner points out, you can just as easily write

```
join $ liftM2 a b c
```

as the equivalent

```
join $ a <$> b <*> c
```

My recommendation of the applicative style is for readability and is a separate point.

Comment: If you're going to use `join`, you can do it without a digression on other styles: `myLiftM2 f x y = join $ liftM2 f x y`.

Comment: True -- I guess I'm recommending both using join and using applicative style independently