# Binding functions that take multiple arguments

Tags: haskell, monads

After reading some very basic haskell now I know how to "chain" monadic actions using *bind*, like:

```
echo = getLine >>= putStrLn
```

`(>>=)` operator is very handy in this fashion, but what if I want to chain monadic actions (or functors) that take multiple arguments?

Given that `(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` it seems like `(>>=)` can supply only one argument.

For example, `writeFile` takes two arguments (a `FilePath` and the contents).  Suppose I have a monadic action that returns a `FilePath`, and another action that returns a `String` to write. How can I combine them with `writeFile`, without using the `do`-notation, but in a general way?

Is there any function with the type:  `m a -> m b -> (a -> b -> m c) -> m c` that can do this?

Comment: First, `putStrLn` is *not* a monad. It's a function that *returns* a monad (the `IO` action). Second, `>>=` (read 'bind') doesn't chain monads directly. It allows you to call functions on monadic values.

Comment: Oh, and btw: `join $ writeFile <$> getFilepath <*> getSomeString`. Figuring out what this does is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Cannot find function similar to liftM2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20163880/1333025).

Comment: @Xeo: An `IO` action is not a monad either.  The `IO` type (and associated instance) is the monad here.

Answer (score 17):

TL;DR:

```
writeFile <$> getFilename <*> getString >>= id   :: IO ()
```

### Monads are Applicative

Since ghc 7.10 every Monad (including `IO`) is also an Applicative, but even before that, you could make an Applicative out of any Monad using the equivalent of

```
import Control.Applicative -- not needed for ghc >= 7.10

instance Applicative M where
  pure x = return x
  mf <*> mx = do
    f <- mf
    x <- mx
    return (f x)
```

And of course `IO` is a functor, but `Control.Applicative` gives you `<$>` which can be defined as `f <$> mx = fmap f mx`.

### Use Applicative to use functions that take as many arguments as you like

`<$>` and `<*>` let you use pure functions `f` over arguments produced by an Applicative/Monadic computation, so if `f :: String -> String -> Bool` and `getFileName, getString :: IO String` then

```
f <$> getFileName <*> getString :: IO Bool
```

Similarly, if `g :: String -> String -> String -> Int`, then

```
g <$> getString <*> getString <*> getString :: IO Int
```

### From `IO (IO ())` to `IO ()`

That means that

```
writeFile <$> getFilename <*> getString :: IO (IO ())
```

but you need something of type `IO ()`, not `IO (IO ())`, so we need to either use `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a` as in [Xeo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115472/combine-monads-that-take-multiple-arguments#comment33550243_22115472), or we need a function to take the monadic result and run it, i.e. of type `(IO ()) -> IO ()` to bind it with. That would be `id` then, so we can either do

```
join $ writeFile <$> getFilename <*> getString :: IO ()
```

or

```
writeFile <$> getFilename <*> getString >>= id :: IO ()
```

Comment: A few sidenotes: `Applicative` is not really necessary, as `ap` exists, which is the same as `<*>`, but with a `Monad` constraint, instead of an `Applicative` one. `join $ return writeFile \`ap\` getFilename \`ap\` getString` would then be another way to write it. Also, `join` is defined as `join m = m >>= id`. That said, _every_ monad should of course have an `Applicative` instance - or the other way around, certain applicatives are also monads. :)

Comment: @Xeo Indeed, and `<*>` is defined a wrapped `ap` for wrapped monads, but the infix notation is prettier and make the transition from `f $ somehow get x $ get y elsehow` psychologically easier.

Comment: @AndrewC the pleasure is all mine. :)

Comment: Just to note, since GHC 7.10, every Monad should be an Applicative. Therefore you can use those applicative operators on Monads without any modification.

Answer (score 7):

It's much easier to use `do` notation for this, rather than asking for a combinator

```
action1 :: MyMonad a
action2 :: MyMonad b
f :: a -> b -> MyMonad c

do
    x <- action1
    y <- action2
    f x y
```

Comment: It might be conceptually easier, but applicative style `f <$> x <*> y >>= id` lifts to a higher abstraction layer (as shown in AndrewC's answer) leading to shorter and (if familiar with) easier-to-read code.

Answer (score 3):

This typechecks:

```
import System.IO

filepath :: IO FilePath
filepath = undefined

someString :: IO String
someString = undefined

testfun = filepath   >>= (\fp -> 
          someString >>= (\str -> 
          writeFile fp str  ))
```

But I feel using do notation is more readable.