# What is the relation and difference between `seqn` and `sequenceA`?

Tags: list, haskell, monads, applicative

```
sequenceA :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]
sequenceA []     = pure []
sequenceA (x:xs) = pure (:) <*> x <*> sequenceA xs
```

From [Programming in Haskell by Hutton](https://books.google.com/books?id=1xHPDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA12&ots=J4QoW9kb4N&dq=This%09flexibility%09is%09captured%09in%09Haskell%09by%09means%09of%09thefollowing%09more%09general%09type%3A&pg=PA12#v=onepage&q=This%09flexibility%09is%09captured%09in%09Haskell%09by%09means%09of%09thefollowing%09more%09general%09type:&f=false)

```
seqn :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

and is its implementation

```
seqn [] = return [] 
seqn (act:acts) = do x<- act 
                  xs <- seqn acts 
                  return (x:xs)
```

What is the relation and difference between `seqn` and `sequenceA`?

Since a monad is an applicative, is `seqn` the `sequenceA` limited to monad?

Comment: by `seqn` I assume you mean [sequence](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence)? (I totally agree with @AJFarmar's comment too.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond, I should note that `sequence` and `mapM` aren't entirely vestigial. The stream fusion system for `vector`, for example, allows a better implementation of `mapM` than of `traverse`.

Comment: the real question here it seems is, what exactly is `<*>` and how it can be related to the monadic `>>=`? of course this question only makes sense for types which have instances of both. in that case, `(<*>)` = [`ap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:ap) (look at their types, they are exactly the same if we swap `Applicative` and `Monad` in their constraint (that part of a type which looks like `Monad a => ...`)). and `ap` [is defined](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#liftM5) in terms of `do`, i.e. `>>=`.

Comment: `sequence` is *the* salient example with which `Applicative` was [originally introduced](http://strictlypositive.org/Idiom.pdf) / invented / discovered. you can search for "difference between Monad and Applicative" (here on SO, and elsewhere) for more context for this. here's [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24467994/849891).

Comment: more about Monad / Applicative correspondence (a.o.t. difference) is e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22117522/849891). But some types allow for a more specialized (more efficient, perhaps) implementation of `<*>` a.o.t. just using `ap`. For such types, `sequence` and `sequenceA` are not necessarily exactly the same thing. Does that answer your question?

Comment: and check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57247698/849891)!

Answer (score 2):

From the link at book ([here](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=75C5DAAAQBAJ&pg=PA12&dq=inauthor:%22Graham%20Hutton%22%20seqn&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIlNGekdjjAhWgDrkGHc21CqkQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=inauthor%3A%22Graham%20Hutton%22%20seqn&f=false)) you added, the type of `seqn` is:

```
seqn :: Monad m -> [m a] -> m [a]
```

and it's implementation is:

```
seqn [] = return []
seqn (act:acts) = do 
                     x  <- act 
                     xs <- seqn acts
                     return (x:xs)
```

And if you look at the type definition of `sequenceA`:

```
sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
```

is more general, since Monad is an applicative, and your implementation:

```
sequenceA []     = pure []
sequenceA (x:xs) = pure (:) <*> x <*> sequenceA xs
```

is essentially the same as `seqn`

> edit:

**To answer the question in the comments** 
I asked a new question to see the differences between one and another. Hope it helps:
[Proving equality of functions from Applicative and Monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57247249/proving-equality-of-functions-from-applicative-and-monad)

> to summarize

There is no `do` notation for applicatives in Haskell, as you can read specifically in [this segment](https://wiki.haskell.org/Do_notation_considered_harmful#Library_design). 
 This is a very nice article: [Desugaring Haskell’s do-Notation into Applicative Operations](https://simonmar.github.io/bib/papers/applicativedo.pdf), and its main idea is how to desugar the `do` notation of monads into applicatives if you want to know.
 `return` and `pure` do exactly the same, but with different constraints, right?, so this part `pure (:)` and this part `return (x:xs)` you can see that are covered.
  Then, here `x  <- act` you are getting the value of `act`, and then the value of the recursion `xs <- seqn acts` , to finally wrap it with the return.

And that's what `pure (:) <*> x <*> sequenceA xs` is essentially doing.