# Proving equivalence of sequence definitions from Applicative and Monad

Tags: list, haskell, monads, applicative, equivalent

How can I properly prove that

```
sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
sequenceA []     = pure []
sequenceA (x:xs) = pure (:) <*> x <*> sequenceA xs
```

is essentially the same to monad inputs as

```
sequenceA' :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
sequenceA' [] = return [] 
sequenceA' (x:xs) = do 
                    x'  <- x 
                    xs' <- sequenceA' xs 
                    return (x':xs')
```

In spite of the constraint `Applicative` and `Monad` of course.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. I won't risk answering and getting storm-downvoted, as I'm fairly recent to Haskell, but if you look at [this paper](https://simonmar.github.io/bib/papers/applicativedo.pdf), they basically answer your question at the end of page 2.

Comment: @MikaelF That’s entirely correct — you should definitely add that as an answer! (Possibly with a quote from the paper at the relevant point.)

Comment: @MikaelF Might also be useful to mention http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative, the documentation of which explicitly states the relation between `<*>` and `ap`.

Comment: I have added Applicative and Monad to the title to improve searchability.  Maybe someone has a better title though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a proof sketch:

1. Show that

   ```
   do
       x'  <- x
       xs' <- sequenceA' xs
       return (x' : xs')
   ```

   is equivalent to

   ```
   do
       f1  <- do
           cons <- return (:)
           x'  <- x
           return (cons x')
       xs' <- sequenceA' xs
       return (f1 xs')
   ```

   This involves desugaring (and resugaring) `do` notation and applying the [Monad laws](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:Monad).
2. Use the [definition of `ap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#ap):

   ```
   ap m1 m2 = do { x1 <- m1; x2 <- m2; return (x1 x2) }
   ```

   to turn the above code into

   ```
   do
       f1  <- return (:) `ap` x
       xs' <- sequenceA' xs
       return (f1 xs')
   ```

   and then

   ```
   return (:) `ap` x `ap` sequenceA' xs
   ```
3. Now you have

   ```
   sequenceA' [] = return [] 
   sequenceA' (x:xs) = return (:) `ap` x `ap` sequenceA' xs
   ```

   Assume that `pure` and `<*>` are essentially the same as `return` and `` `ap` ``, respectively, and you're done.

   This latter property is also stated in the [Applicative documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative):

   > If `f` is also a `Monad`, it should satisfy
   >
   > - `pure = return`
   > - `(<*>) = ap`

Answer (score 8):

Since the [Functor-Applicative-Monad proposal](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal), implemented in GHC 7.10, Applicative is a superclass of Monad. So even though your two functions can't be strictly equivalent, since `sequenceA`'s domain includes `sequenceA'`'s domain, we can look at what happens in this common domain (the `Monad` typeclass).

[This paper](https://simonmar.github.io/bib/papers/applicativedo.pdf) shows an interesting demonstration of desugaring `do` notation to applicative and functor operations (`<$>`, `pure` and `<*>`). If the expressions on the right hand side of your left-pointing arrows (`<-`) don't depend on each other, as is the case in your question, you can always use applicative operations, and therefore show that your hypothesis is correct (for the `Monad` domain).

Also have a look at the [ApplicativeDo](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/applicative-do) language extension proposal, which contains an example that's just like yours:

```
do
  x <- a
  y <- b
  return (f x y)
```

which translates to:

```
(\x y -> f x y) <$> a <*> b
```

Substituting `f` for `(:)`, we get:

```
do
  x <- a
  y <- b
  return (x : y)
```

... which translates to...

```
(\x y -> x : y) <$> a <*> b
--And by eta reduction
(:) <$> a <*> b
--Which is equivalent to the code in your question (albeit more general):
pure (:) <*> a <*> b
```

Alternatively, you can make GHC's desugarer work for you by using the `ApplicativeDo` language extension and by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8019870/7096763) to the SO question "haskell - Desugaring do-notation for Monads". I'll leave this exercise up to you (as it honestly goes beyond my capacities!).

Answer (score 0):

> My own two cents

There is no do notation for applicatives in Haskell. It can be seen specifically in [this segment](https://wiki.haskell.org/Do_notation_considered_harmful#Library_design).

`return` and `pure` do exactly the same, but with different constraints, right?, so this part `pure (:)` and this part `return (x:xs)` are essentially the same.

Then, here `x  <- act` you are getting the value of act, and then the value of the recursion `xs <- seqn acts`, to finally wrap it with the `return`.

And that's what `pure (:) <*> x <*> sequenceA xs` is essentially doing.

Comment: there's ApplicativeDo extension. as for wiki, it's largely abandoned, isn't it? you can check any page's history there, to see how recent / relevant it really is.